# Adding authentication to PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm running the following PowerShell command:

```
$colDisks = get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk 
    -ComputerName $strComputer
    -Filter "DriveType = 3"
```

But I'm not having enough privileges to run this command for remote servers.

How can I add an authentification to this command to have more privileges?

Comment: You could use [runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) to start PowerShell as a different user.

Comment: I need to include it in the script.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/robcost/archive/2008/05/01/powershell-tip-storing-and-using-password-credentials.aspx

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$colDisks = get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk
    -ComputeNname $strComputer
    -Filter "DriveType = 3"
    -Credential (get-credential)
```

Comment: I need to enter my own credentiels, not windows one

Comment: You can enter a different account credentials with `Get-Credential`. Try it. Username format will be `domainname\username` or (for a local user account) `computername\username`.